# BigQuery - Firebase Analytics vs Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

How can I correlate firebase crashlytics events with firebase analytics events with BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user3600910 noted, one important first step is linking your Firebase project to BigQuery and making sure you're exporting your Crashlytics and Analytics data there.

However, that won't be enough to connect the two data sets in BigQuery. You're going to need to find a way to connect the same user across both datasets. Probably the easiest way to do that would be to use the [`setUserID`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid)  call in Analytics, and the [`setUserIdentifier`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports) call in Crashlytics. Those values will then show up in your Analytics BigQuery table as `user_id` and your Crashlytics BigQuery table as `user.id`. So if you set those to the same value,  then you should be able to JOIN those tables together.

Answer (score 0):

- click in the settings in the upper right corner in the project
- click on the integration tab
- click on BigQuery
- choose all the data sources you like to upload to BigQuery,

see attached link:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en

Comment: I already have the two projects in BigQuery. However, I have 2 separate tables and I need to know if there is a way to correlate a crashlytics event with an analytics event.

Comment: unfortunately not in a easy way since the events stretcher is different from the crashlytics events , in case you like to marge them my suggestion is to set event name for each transaction type but then you need to adjust the schema